# ChatterBot does not get trained with ubuntu corpus

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, corpus, chatterbot

i followed [this example](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/training_example_ubuntu_corpus.py) to train my chatterbot with Ubuntu corpus

my code is the next:

```
# import ChatBot
from chatterbot import ChatBot
# import Trainer
from chatterbot.trainers import UbuntuCorpusTrainer

# Declare a bot
bot = ChatBot('Zeus')

# Training
trainer3 = UbuntuCorpusTrainer(bot)
# Start by training our bot with the Ubuntu corpus data
trainer3.train()

# Get a response to an input statement
bot.get_response("Hello, how are you today?")

while True:
    # Input from user
    message = input('You: ')
    # if message is not "Bye"
    if message.strip() != 'Bye':
        reply = bot.get_response(message)
        print('Zeus:', reply)
        # if message is "Bye"
    if message.strip() == 'Bye':
        print('Zeus: Bye')
        break
```

The output shows that the bot does not get trained with ubuntu corpus:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /home/user/Documents/python-workspace/zeus_bot/UbuntuCorpus.py
[nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
[nltk_data]     /home/user/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package averaged_perceptron_tagger is already up-to-
[nltk_data]       date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to /home/user/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
Training took 0.11888790130615234 seconds.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chatterbot/corpus.py:38: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  return yaml.load(data_file)
You: Hi
Zeus: Hello, how are you today?
You: very well
Zeus: Hi
You: what news?
Zeus: Hello, how are you today?
You: i am fine
Zeus: Hi
You: Bye
Zeus: Bye

Process finished with exit code 0
```

it does not show a loading process for training.
when i chat with the bot i get only the get response and nothing else.

Comment: i have downloaded the ubuntu_dialogs.tgz at /home/user/ubuntu_data and untar it at /home/user/ubuntu_data/ubuntu_dialogs/ Inside this folder have other numbered folders with *.tsv files

Comment: If you see the logs, you'll notice that the training has already been done, that is why you not see the full training process. If you want to add your own training data you should create your own trainer class:

See here for examples
https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/chatterbot/trainers.py

Comment: No there is no training, no db sqlite, and no response from the bot

Comment: @demosthenes, how have you managed to train the chatbot with the UbuntuCorpusTrainer? I tried multiple times and, after the first time I  was always receiving the following info: *INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:File is already downloaded* 
*INFO:chatterbot.chatterbot:File is already extracted*. Then the script stopped  responding.

Comment: @Apostolos it has pass too much time from when i tried chatbot. As i remember the download link of tarball of Ubuntu corpus was broken. I searched the internet with Google and i found the tarball from another site and download it with wget. Then i put it to appropriate location on my file system so chat bot see it and train chatbot this way.

Comment: @demosthenes, the download link si still alive. In fact the trainer has downloaded the TGZ file and extracted the TSV files. The problem, as I found out with debugging, is that it tries to process 25,000+ TSV files to create a ChatterBot DB! And this of course takes hours.. And the developer of the UbuntuCorpusTrainer class didn't even care to warn about this and, better, to show a progress of the process as in other trainers, like ChatterBotCorpusTrainer, do. In shoer, it's a question of slipshod programming.

Comment: BTW, have you dropped ChatterBot only or chatbot programming in general? I'm asking to know if you have found something better. (ChatterBot doesn't say much. Can't see any AI involved in the responses. It works like chatting in the 80s .or 90s, based on know prompts and responses.)

Comment: @Apostolos i don't know of chatbot programming. I used it as user

Comment: Yes, training with Ubuntu corpus takes too much time...you have to wait.

Comment: @demosthenes, please see my answer that follows.

Answer (score -1):

There's no problem with the Ubuntu trainer iself. It works. The problem is that it tries to create a ChatterBot DB from 25,000+ TSV files at once! This can take, as I have calculated from tests, from 12 to 15 hours! Moreover, they don’t show the progress of the process or even any information that one has to wait for such a long time. Only an idiot could distribute do such module.

Well, I have created a script that creates a ChatterBot DB from a selection of TSV files included in the Ubuntu dialogs TGZ, which can be very fast depending on the amount of TSV files you select to be processed. Note also the size of the DBs can be very large. A DB carrying the whole package will be about 500 MB! (I have not tried to create such a monster of course. But I guess the interaction with it will be quite fruitful!

For anyone who is interested and can program in Python, the UbuntuCorpusTrainer class is found in 'trainers.py' of the 'chatterbot' package. You can adjust it to use a specific list of TSV files instead of creating a huge list of all the TSV files stored in the default directory 'dialogs'.(In my case, this is 'C:\Users{username}\ubuntu_data\ubuntu_dialogs\dialogs'.) A process, as I said, it has no end!

For anyone who is interested, I can provide the basic code.  processed. Note also the size of the DBs can be very large. A DB carrying the whole package will be about 500 MB! (I have not tried to create such a monster of course. But I guess the interaction with it would be quite interesting!)

For anyone who is interested and can program in Python, the UbuntuCorpusTrainer class is found in 'trainers.py' of the 'chatterbot' package. You can adjust it to use a specific list of TSV files instead of creating a huge list of all the TSV files stored in the default directory 'dialogs'.(In my case, this is 'C:\Users{username}\ubuntu_data\ubuntu_dialogs\dialogs'.) A process, as I said, it has no end!

For anyone who is interested, I can provide the basic code.